# What is the meaning of double brackets within a Clojure function definition's parameters?

Tags: clojure

```
(defn foo [[a] b]
  (println a b))

(foo "one" "two") ; => o two

(foo 1 2) ; => Execution error (UnsupportedOperationException) at user/foo (REPL:1).
          ;    nth not supported on this type: Long
```

What are the second pair of brackets around `a` doing?

Or, a real-world [example](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer/tree/55188100144567961c7a4216337592705e08d950#internationalization) where I encountered it:

```
(parser/add-tag! :i18n
  (fn [[k] context]
    (->> k (keyword) (translate (or (:i18n/locale context) :en)))))
```

Answer (score 6):

It is Clojure's syntax for [destructuring](https://gist.github.com/john2x/e1dca953548bfdfb9844).

```
(defn bar [[a b] c]
  (println a b c))
```

would "pull out" the first and second items from the first argument passed to `bar` and immediately assign them to variables `a` and `b` respectively. It is functionally equivalent to:

```
(defn bar [vector c]
  (let [a (nth vector 0)  ; assign first item in first parameter to a
        b (nth vector 1)] ; assign second item in first parameter to b
    (println a b c)))     ; c is passed & printed as-is
```

---

In your example:

```
(defn foo [[a] b]
  (println a b))
```

Running `(foo "one" "two")` would mean "set `a` to first item in `"one"` and `b` to `"two"`, then print `a b`.

In Clojure, strings are [seq-able](https://clojurebridge.org/community-docs/docs/clojure/string/), so `[[a]]` in this specific case means "set `a` to the first character of the string `"one"`, which is `o`.

`(foo 1 2)` fails because numbers (Longs) are **not** seq-able, so they cannot be destructured.

---

`(fn [[k] context] … )` would mean "of the two arguments passed into this function, take the first item from the first argument and set it as `k`. Leave the second argument as-is."

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is [*sequential* destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_sequential_destructuring), not the [associative](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_associative_destructuring) kind.

Comment: @Thumbnail Thanks! Coming from JS, that answers something I didn't quite know in my answer: the term for pulling out elements by their index, rather than their key. Feel free to edit that in!